# Loop through strings within a struct in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, dataValues> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, dataValues>();

public struct dataValues
    {
        public string Value1;
        public string Value2;
        public string Value3;
        public string Value4;
        public string Value5;
        public string Value6;
        public string Value7;
        public string Value8;
        public string Value9;
        public string Value10;
        public string Value11;
        public string Value12;
        public string Value13;
        public string Value14;
        public string Value15;
        public string Value16;
        public string Value17;
        public string Value18;
        public string Value19;
        public string Value20;
    }
```

I would like to be able to iterate through all of the string within the dataValues struct by specifying a dictionary key - how could this be accomplished?

Comment: Use a `List<String>` instead of those string variables.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I can't do, because I need to assign / call specific values in a certain order and I can't do that with a list

Comment: Sure you can, lists are indexable. So are arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment: Use a `List<String>` instead of those string variables.

> @Tim Schmelter I can't do, because I need to assign / call specific
>   values in a certain order and I can't do that with a list

Use the indexer of the collection.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// initialization ...
String val20OfData1 = dataDict["Data1"][19];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write a customer enumerator for dataValues that returns each member variables in term, or even use reflection to retrieve all the fields ... but why not simply use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 20 properties in your struct ? It will be best if you storage them in an `List`:

```
public struct dataValues
    {
        public List<string> Values;
    }
```

you could do something like :

```
foreach(string value in dataDict["yourKey"].Values)
{
//do what ever you want with value here
}
```

Also, if your struct is only a `List`, use it directly, no need to create a struct

So, it will be  `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

and then

```
foreach(string value in dataDict["yourKey"])
    {
    //do what ever you want with value here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you are trying to do. Anyway, if you must use separate string variables inside your struct you could use reflection in this way:

```
        dataValues dv = dataDict["yourKey"];
        Type dvT = dv.GetType();
        FieldInfo[] fis = dvT.GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo fi in fis)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fi.GetValue(dv) as string);
        }
```